# Maven plugin with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to assemble Maven plugin with eclipse. For that I have already installed the m2eclipse. Now, in the new project, I have created a new Maven project.

When I try to run it by right clicking to the application, there are several options available.

When I run as Maven build, it gives **build faliure** but if I run as any other option such as maven install or maven clean or maven test, it gives **build success**.

Why so ?

Comment: Does you build work on command line? You are trying to package an maven plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, I am not familier with using command line. I am using directly Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On right click, when you do maven build, enter the command **clean install** and then try.

Comment: where should I write **clean install** ? in Goal ?

Comment: Yeah. I got it.Can you further explain a little bit why this happens ?

Comment: How can I reset the goal ?

Comment: If you want to reset the goal, try the next **Maven Build** option and it will let you enter another goal., then every time you build, you'll be prompted to choose between the two goals.

Comment: Also, if this helped, please accept the answer. And one more thing, if problem persists please list the build failure message as well to get more of the problem.

Comment: @Rujvendra I want to learn working with Maven using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: This is the nice tutorial for learning maven step by step  follow this  http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/

Comment: I once created a ppt on maven through eclipse, a very basic one. Hope this helps
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5dpzztnm2lahw8/Maven_Eclipse.pptx